# A list of php error

Tags: php, mysql, post

> Notice: Undefined index: Email in C:\xampp\htdocs******.php on line
>   14
>
> Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs******.php on line 17
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs******.php on line 17
>
> Notice: Undefined index: Email in C:\xampp\htdocs******.php on line
>   34

```
     <?php  
if(isset($_POST['Login']))
{

$query_login = "select * from tbl_member where pass = '".md5(md5($_POST['Email']).$_POST['password'])."' and user_name = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle, $_POST['username'])."' || email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle, $_POST['username'])."' and activation = '1'";

$sql_login=mysqli_query($dbhandle, $query_login);
    if(mysqli_num_rows((int)$sql_login>0)){

        // The log-in is OK so set the user ID and username session vars (and cookies), and redirect to the home page
        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_login);

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['id'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $result['user_name'];

      setcookie('user_id', $result['id'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
      setcookie('username', $result['user_name'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));
    $query_check = "select * from tbl_member where user_name = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle, $_POST['username'])."' || email = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($dbhandle, $_POST['username'])."' and pass = '".md5(md5($_POST['Email']).$_POST['password'])."' and activation = '0'";
        $sql_check=mysqli_query($dbhandle, $query_check);

        $msg = "<font style='font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;color:red'>ERROR:-Invalid email or password !</font>";

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I see no question here, but a bunch of errors.

Comment: You've got more than enough information in your error log to debug this yourself.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be question. You can use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error #2 and #3:**

You have written a bit nonsense to the if() statement, mixed parts of what you intended to do.

replace these two lines

```
if(mysqli_num_rows((int)$sql_login>0)){
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_login);
```

with this one line

```
if( $result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_login) ){
```

Description of said one line code: If there is a record, $result will become an array, which is always equivalent to 'true', if not, it will be set to 'false' value. Then, this $result is passed to if() evaluation. No need to check for number of rows. There either will be at least one and script will continue, or not.

**Error #1 and #4:**

The other thing is PHP says there is no 'Email' value in POST data. Check your login form if it contains this field, is well formed and how exactly it is named. I think you meant 'username' instead

**Error #5:**

These last few rows, althrough they are just in the body of if(/*login correct?*/) I believe that one query is part of unfinished code about activation process and that error message at the end should be moved out of this if(), to else{} body, as it informs about unsuccessful login.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is not correct. This should be:

`if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_login) > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your code, you do not have a mysql connection.

Put this on top of your script:

```
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```